# Why is this question about terminology bad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I wonder why the question [What is the term for being younger than the body age?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/39891/6786) has 2 downvotes?

Comment: You got some feedback in the comments that are probably related; it's still unclear to me why the suggested answer in a comment, that you eventually turned into an actual answer, actually relates to the question you asked. The wording of the question seems very disorganized and tangential.

Comment: I see. Probably this would require a lot of effort to ask specific questions why you feel unclear, disorganized and tangential. I have tried my best to make it clear. Thanks for your time